# Deleting a folder from the documentsDirectory with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems, documentsdirectory

I have created a VideoAssets folder within documentsDirectory as below, which can contain one or more video assets:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2E3H5FDD-825D-407A-A8BE-71CD540A6E15/Documents/VideoAssets/ae6e4f59be0bc5984b043e.mp4
```

Periodically it needs to be cleaned out. How can I either empty the folder OR remove the VideoAssets folder in it's entirety? There's a fair bit of info out there for creating folders, but not for removing one.

Comment: do you get the path of `video` like shown above ??? , show the code of getting that path

Answer (score 6):

Just use `try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: directoryUrl)`

From Apple's docs:

> A file URL specifying the file or directory to remove. If the URL specifies a directory, the contents of that directory are recursively removed. You may specify nil for this parameter.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413590-removeitem

Comment: Correct, thanks. As noted in my own answer I had to convert the path back to a string and remove the file:// component first.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to my own question:

When calling `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: directory)` I was erroneously passing a URL and not a string, but also `file://` had to be removed first.

I was then able to successfully delete a file within the newly created folder using removeItem: `try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: directoryUrl)`